# Unity UI elements flaky texture glitch on Android Builds

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am building a Unity app for Android and sometimes I see this weird texture glitch on UI buttons.

[image: UI buttons texture glitch]

Interesting thing is that I can't reproduce this bug when I run app in the editor or run on my device after building using Unity Editor. However it inconsistently reproduces when app installed from Google Play or from APKs build by my CI pipeline.

At the same time other textures on the canvas are displayed normally. (Can my problem be caused by use of Layouts components?)

Sometimes also Unity icon on splash-screen have the same glitch.

I am wondering if anybody saw this issue before and if there is a remedy.

Unity version I use is: 2019.2.9f1